# Which statement is false ?(Linear algebra problem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, orthogonal-matrices

Let $P=\dfrac{xx^{T}}{x^{T}x}$ be an a square matrix of order n  where $x$ is a non zero column vector. Then which one of the following statement is False.

$(A)$ P is idempotent

$(B)$ P is orthogonal

$(C)$ P is symmetric

$(D)$ Rank of P is one

In this question i only know that rank of $xx^{T}$ is $1$. And some short notes i have in my mind  are :

Eigen values of idempotent matrix are $0$ and $1$.

Eigen values of orthogonal matrix are $-1$ and $1$.

Eigen values of symmetric matrix are Real. But that is not sufficient for this problem i guess. I don't know how to deal rational functions in linear algebra. Please give me some knowledge i just started learning algebra.

Comment: This is a orthogonal projection  matrix onto a line of the vector $x$. Evidently B is false. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas

Comment: You don't need to do anything with eigenvalues here. Simply calculate the expressions. For example $$ P^2 = \frac{(xx^T)(xx^T)}{(x^Tx)(x^Tx)} = \frac{x(x^Tx)x^T}{(x^Tx)^2} = \frac{xx^T}{x^Tx} = P$$ Note that $(x^Tx)$ is just a scalar!

Comment: @Hyperplane "Note that (..) is just a scalar" can you tell me how?

Comment: @Damn1o1 By assumption $x$ is a column vector, so a $n\times 1$ matrix. So $x^T x$ is the product of a $1\times n$ matrix with a $n\times 1$ matrix which is $1\times 1$, i.e. a scalar.

Comment: @Hyperplane OHH Yes nice  thanks. :) I am enjoying maths.

Comment: @Hyperplane Can you tell me if was right about eigen values of orthogonal matrix ?

Comment: @Damn1o1 Not really. It is true that the eigenvalues of an orthogonal/unitary matrix always have absolute value $1$, and if the matrix is real then its complex eigenvalues always come up in complex conjugated pairs. For example the real orthogonal $2\times 2$ rotation matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}\cos x& \sin x \\ -\sin x & \cos x \end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues $\lambda = e^{\pm i x}$.

Comment: $\lambda = e^{\pm i x}$ has magnitude 1? How do i check that?How to calculate magnitude of complex number can you tell me with an example otherwise i have to go through a whole youtube video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is idempotent it can't be orthogonal because:$$PP^T=P^TP=\dfrac{xx^Txx^T}{x^Txx^Tx}=\dfrac{x^Txxx^T}{x^Txx^Tx}=\dfrac{xx^T}{x^Tx}=P\ne I$$

Comment: Can you tell me if was right about eigen values of orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix of rank $1 $ cannot be orthogonal.  Orthogonal matrices have maximal rank.

Comment: Numerator has rank one what about denominator ?

Comment: Denominator is a real number, it can't do anything.

Comment: Hey one more thing. Can you tell me if was right about eigen values of orthogonal matrix ?